# How to feed json from file to aws kinesis put-record

Tags: bash, unix, amazon-kinesis

How to supply content of the file containing json to aws kinesis put-record?

I'd tried  `aws kinesis put-record --stream-name test_event --partition-key 1 --cli-input-json < file.json`but got `argument --cli-input-json: expected one argument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

Use

`--cli-input-json file://file.json`

instead of

`--cli-input-json < file.json`

#### Update - Sharing valid sample json for the command `aws kinesis put-record`

```
{
    "StreamName": "",
    "Data": null,
    "PartitionKey": "",
    "ExplicitHashKey": "",
    "SequenceNumberForOrdering": ""
}
```

The same can be obtained via `aws kinesis put-record --generate-cli-skeleton`

Comment: Didn't work. aws kinesis put-record --stream-name isome_event --partition-key 1 --cli-input-json file://~/temp/bad.json I am getting "Missing required parameter in input: "Data""

Comment: @O'Leg I think it is a problem with the json. Could you please post the json in the question. Also, I'm adding a sample json which is valid syntax in the answer.

Comment: When you use --cli-input-json, you need to provide all fields in json. If you only want to provide the kinesis stream data via json, do this instead - `--data file://file.json` instead of --cli-input-json